# How do I make multiple graphs without coding every data of the graphs?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make an app that shows a graph for each location on the map that I set. But the data for each location is obviously different, and I'm trying to use a way to minimize code length. I don't want to code in every piece of data I need. Instead, I want to get the data from an external file that represents the location's data. Or I heard there was something you could do with JSON files? Please give me some advice on this matter.